# Use pyplot.scatter() in Jupyter Notebook makes bug in the Jupyter notebook menu

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The image of the jupyter notebook menu error:

[image: Image of the jupyter notebook menu error.]

My code as follow:

```
[%matplotlib inline
import torch
from IPython import display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

num_inputs = 2
num_examples = 1000
true_w = [2, -3.4]
true_b = 4.2
features = torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(0, 1, (num_examples, num_inputs)))

labels = true_w[0] * features[:, 0] + true_w[1] * features[:, 1] + true_b
labels += torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, size=labels.size()))

def use_svg_display():
    display.set_matplotlib_formats('svg')

def set_figsize(figsize=(3.5, 2.5)):
    use_svg_display()
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = figsize

set_figsize()
plt.scatter(features[:, 1].numpy(), labels.numpy(), 1);
```

My environment is: Windows 10, Anaconda, Python3.6. When executing the last line, this problem occured. I have looked through the Internet but have no idea what't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your corrected code, it looks like this is an error with the svg rendering in your matplotlib version. See [this github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14552) about the same problem. It looks like you'll want to update your matplotlib version to 3.1.1 or revert to 3.0.3 as suggested in the post, by doing
`conda install matplotlib=3.0.3` in the terminal and restarting your notebook.

Comment: Sorry for that, i edit the question and correct the mistake of the code. But it still doesn't work for me, the menu of Jupyter Notebook still makes an error.

Comment: Does the notebook look like this before running any cells?

Comment: No, only ofter this cell the notebook crash.